# CSS issue on the height of my menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an issue on my top menu, the height of the subcategory "Por colores" (when is selected), also the childs of that subcategory have the incorrect height.

my site is: [www.dulcewashitape.com](http://www.dulcewashitape.com/)

here's is the css file:

```
/*** ESSENTIAL STYLES ***/
.sf-contener {
clear: both;
}
.sf-right {
  margin-right: 14px;
  float: right;
  width: 7px;
}
.sf-menu, .sf-menu * {
margin: 0;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
list-style: none;
}
.sf-menu {
margin: 10px 0;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
width:980px;/* 980 */
background: #383838;
/*  @media (max-width: 450px) {
    .sf-menu {
      display: none; }    */
}
.sf-menu ul {
position: absolute;
top: -999em;
width: 10em; /* left offset of submenus need to match (see below) */
}
.sf-menu ul li {
width: 100%;
}

.sf-menu li ul {
    display: none;
}



.sf-menu li:hover {
visibility: inherit; /* fixes IE7 'sticky bug' */
}
.sf-menu li {
float: left;
position: relative;
top: 0;
/*border-right: 1px solid #777;*/
}
.sf-menu a {
display: block;
position: relative;
color:#fff;
}
.sf-menu li:hover ul,
.sf-menu li.sfHover ul {
left: 0;
/*padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;*/
top: 35px; /* match top ul list item height */
z-index: 99;
width:auto;
}
ul.sf-menu li:hover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li.sfHover li ul {
top: -999em;
}
ul.sf-menu li li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover ul {
left: 200px; /* match ul width */
top: 0;
}
ul.sf-menu li li:hover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover li ul {
left: 200px; /* match ul width */
top: 0;
}
ul.sf-menu li li li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li li.sfHover ul {
left: 200px; /* match ul width */
top: 0;
}


/*** DEMO SKIN ***/
.cat-title {
display: none;
}
.sf-menu {
float: left;
margin-bottom: -2em;
width: 100%;
height: 75px;
background: url('http://www.dulcewashitape.com/themes/dulcewashitape/img/cabecera.png') repeat left center; 

}
.sf-menu a {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  display:block;
    margin-right:2px;
    padding: 0 22px 0 20px;
    line-height:35px;   
    border: 10;
    text-decoration:none; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family:Handlee;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  { /* visited pseudo selector so IE6 applies text colour*/
color: #916e6e;
white-space:nowrap;
}
.sf-menu li ul {
  border:1px solid #f1b6b1; box-shadow:2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  width:500px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 23px 0px 0px 0px;
  top:0;
  background: white;
}
.sf-menu li li {
background: white; 
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height:35px; 
  line-height:35px; 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

}
.sf-menu li li a {
font-size: 16px;
text-transform: capitalize;
top:0;  
}
ul.sf-menu li:first-child a:first-child {
  padding-right: 2.25em;
  min-width: 1px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
/*
ul.sf-menu li a {
  padding-right: 2.25em;
  min-width: 1px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
*/

.sf-menu li li li {
background: white;
width:140px;
}
.sf-menu a:focus, .sf-menu a:hover, .sf-menu a:active {
   font-weight: bold; 
   color: white;
   background: url('http://www.dulcewashitape.com/themes/dulcewashitape/img/boton-b.png') no-repeat center 0px; 
}
.sf-menu ul li:hover, .sf-menu ul li.sfHover,
.sf-menu ul li a:focus, .sf-menu ul li a:hover, .sf-menu ul li a:active {
background: #eecfd0; //#4e4e4e; 
outline: 0;
} 
/*** arrows **/
.sf-menu a.sf-with-ul {
padding-right:  2.25em;
min-width: 1px; /* trigger IE7 hasLayout so spans position accurately */
padding-top: 20px;
margin-top: -20px;
}
.sf-sub-indicator {
position: absolute;
display: block;
right: 10px;
top: 1.05em; /* IE6 only */
width: 10px;
height: 35px;
text-indent:  -999em;
overflow: hidden;
background: url('../img/arrows-ffffff.png') no-repeat -10px -100px; /* 8-bit indexed alpha png. IE6 gets solid image only */
}
a > .sf-sub-indicator {  /* give all except IE6 the correct values */
top: 11px;
background-position: 0 -100px; /* use translucent arrow for modern browsers*/
}
/* apply hovers to modern browsers */
a:focus > .sf-sub-indicator,
a:hover > .sf-sub-indicator,
a:active > .sf-sub-indicator,
li:hover > a > .sf-sub-indicator,
li.sfHover > a > .sf-sub-indicator {
background-position: -10px -100px; /* arrow hovers for modern browsers*/
}


/* point right for anchors in subs */
.sf-menu ul .sf-sub-indicator { background-position:  -10px 0; }
.sf-menu ul a > .sf-sub-indicator { background-position:  0 0; }
/* apply hovers to modern browsers */
.sf-menu ul a:focus > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul a:hover > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul a:active > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul li:hover > a > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul li.sfHover > a > .sf-sub-indicator {
background-position: -10px 0; /* arrow hovers for modern browsers*/
}


/*** shadows for all but IE6 ***/
.sf-shadow ul {
background: url('../img/shadow.png') no-repeat bottom right;
padding: 0 8px 9px 0;
-moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 17px;
-moz-border-top-right-radius: 17px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 17px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 17px;
}
.sf-shadow ul.sf-shadow-off {
background: transparent;
}
li.sf-search {
  background: inherit;
  float: right;
  line-height: 25px;
  background:transparent;
}
li.sf-search input {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin: 18px 6px 0 0;
  background: #fff url('../../../../img/search-zoom3.png') no-repeat left center;
  border:1px solid #777;
}


/* hack IE7 */
.sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited {height:34px !IE;}
.sf-menu li li {
width:200px;
background:#726f72 !IE;
}

#block_top_menu .category-thumbnail {
  display:none;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  float: none; }
  #block_top_menu .category-thumbnail div {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33333%; }
    #block_top_menu .category-thumbnail div img {
      max-width: 100%; }
#block_top_menu li.category-thumbnail {
  padding-right: 0; }




/* Mobile Item */
.sf-menu-phone-item { display:none; }
#sf-menu-phone-trigger { display:none; position:absolute; top:7px; right:0; background:url('http://www.dulcewashitape.com/themes/dulcewashitape/img/icon-mobile-nav.png') top right no-repeat #29addd; width:50px; height:50px; text-indent:-9999px; border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s; }
#sf-menu-phone-trigger:hover { background-color:#333; }
#sf-menu-phone-trigger.active { background-position:bottom right; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 999px) {
    .sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  {font-size:13px;}
}
/* Tablet Only Queries */
@media only screen and (min-width: 531px) and (max-width: 786px)  { 
    .sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  {font-size:12px;}
}

/* Phone Only Queries */
@media only screen and (max-width: 530px) { 
    .sf-menu a{
        top:5px;
    }
    #sf-menu-header {height:auto; }
    #sf-menu-top-nav {margin-left:-2%; margin-right:-2%;}
    /*.sf-menu {display:none; } */
    .sf-menu {width:100%; height:auto; margin:10px 0 0 0; position:static !important}
    .sf-menu li {width:100%; background:#f4f4f4;  border-top:1px solid #fff !important; border-bottom:1px solid #999 !important; -webkit-border-radius:0; border-radius:0; }
    .sf-menu li:hover {background:#de8686;}
    .sf-menu li ul {width:100%; position:static !important; background:#ccc;}
    .sf-menu li li {width:100% !important; background:#ccc; }
    /*.sf-menu li li li {display:none !important;}*/
    .sf-menu-phone-item { display:block; }
    #sf-menu-phone-trigger { display:block; }
    .sf-search {padding:10px;} 
    #searchbox {margin-left:15px;}
    #searchbox input[type="text"] {width:80%;}
    #searchbox input[type="text"]:focus, #searchbox input[type="text"]:hover {width:80%;}
    #searchbox .button {width:10%;}
    #header_logo { padding-right:50px; text-align:left !important;}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure what is a your aim, but you are adding padding-top='20px' to each "a" element in "ul" list:
`ul.sf-menu li:first-child a:first-child `

If you want shift whole second list down, you can try add margin-top to 'ul' list.

Comment: I don't see the issue. The "Por colores" menu item has the same height as the other menu items (35px, as specified in the stylesheet). Is there a particular browser you're viewing this with?

Answer (score 0):

you have been used padding unnecessarily twice i have removed those just check with this style and let me know if there any other further problem

css:

```
/*** ESSENTIAL STYLES ***/
.sf-contener {
clear: both;
}
.sf-right {
  margin-right: 14px;
  float: right;
  width: 7px;
}
.sf-menu, .sf-menu * {
margin: 0;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
list-style: none;
}
.sf-menu {
margin: 10px 0;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
width:980px;/* 980 */
background: #383838;
/*  @media (max-width: 450px) {
    .sf-menu {
      display: none; }    */
}
.sf-menu ul {
position: absolute;
top: -999em;
width: 10em; /* left offset of submenus need to match (see below) */
}
.sf-menu ul li {
width: 100%;
}

.sf-menu li ul {
    display: none;
}



.sf-menu li:hover {
visibility: inherit; /* fixes IE7 'sticky bug' */
}
.sf-menu li {
float: left;
position: relative;
top: 0;
/*border-right: 1px solid #777;*/
}
.sf-menu a {
display: block;
position: relative;
color:#fff;
}
.sf-menu li:hover ul,
.sf-menu li.sfHover ul {
left: 0;
/*padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;*/
top: 35px; /* match top ul list item height */
z-index: 99;
width:auto;
}
ul.sf-menu li:hover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li.sfHover li ul {
top: -999em;
}
ul.sf-menu li li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover ul {
left: 200px; /* match ul width */
top: 0;
}
ul.sf-menu li li:hover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover li ul {
left: 200px; /* match ul width */
top: 0;
}
ul.sf-menu li li li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li li.sfHover ul {
left: 200px; /* match ul width */
top: 0;
}


/*** DEMO SKIN ***/
.cat-title {
display: none;
}
.sf-menu {
float: left;
margin-bottom: -2em;
width: 100%;
height: 75px;
background: url('http://www.dulcewashitape.com/themes/dulcewashitape/img/cabecera.png') repeat left center; 

}
.sf-menu a {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  display:block;
    margin-right:2px;
    padding: 0 22px 0 20px;
    line-height:35px;   
    border: 10;
    text-decoration:none; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family:Handlee;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  { /* visited pseudo selector so IE6 applies text colour*/
color: #916e6e;
white-space:nowrap;
}
.sf-menu li ul {
  border:1px solid #f1b6b1; box-shadow:2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  width:500px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 23px 0px 0px 0px;
  top:0;
  background: white;
}
.sf-menu li li {
background: white; 
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height:35px; 
  line-height:35px; 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

}
.sf-menu li li a {
font-size: 16px;
text-transform: capitalize;
top:0;  
}
ul.sf-menu li:first-child a:first-child {
  padding-right: 2.25em;
  min-width: 1px;
}
/*
ul.sf-menu li a {
  padding-right: 2.25em;
  min-width: 1px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
*/

.sf-menu li li li {
background: white;
width:140px;
}
.sf-menu a:focus, .sf-menu a:hover, .sf-menu a:active {
   font-weight: bold; 
   color: white;
   background: url('http://www.dulcewashitape.com/themes/dulcewashitape/img/boton-b.png') no-repeat center 0px; 
}
.sf-menu ul li:hover, .sf-menu ul li.sfHover,
.sf-menu ul li a:focus, .sf-menu ul li a:hover, .sf-menu ul li a:active {
background: #eecfd0; //#4e4e4e; 
outline: 0;
} 
/*** arrows **/
.sf-menu a.sf-with-ul {
padding-right:  2.25em;
min-width: 1px; /* trigger IE7 hasLayout so spans position accurately */
}
.sf-sub-indicator {
position: absolute;
display: block;
right: 10px;
top: 1.05em; /* IE6 only */
width: 10px;
height: 35px;
text-indent:  -999em;
overflow: hidden;
background: url('../img/arrows-ffffff.png') no-repeat -10px -100px; /* 8-bit indexed alpha png. IE6 gets solid image only */
}
a > .sf-sub-indicator {  /* give all except IE6 the correct values */
top: 11px;
background-position: 0 -100px; /* use translucent arrow for modern browsers*/
}
/* apply hovers to modern browsers */
a:focus > .sf-sub-indicator,
a:hover > .sf-sub-indicator,
a:active > .sf-sub-indicator,
li:hover > a > .sf-sub-indicator,
li.sfHover > a > .sf-sub-indicator {
background-position: -10px -100px; /* arrow hovers for modern browsers*/
}


/* point right for anchors in subs */
.sf-menu ul .sf-sub-indicator { background-position:  -10px 0; }
.sf-menu ul a > .sf-sub-indicator { background-position:  0 0; }
/* apply hovers to modern browsers */
.sf-menu ul a:focus > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul a:hover > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul a:active > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul li:hover > a > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul li.sfHover > a > .sf-sub-indicator {
background-position: -10px 0; /* arrow hovers for modern browsers*/
}


/*** shadows for all but IE6 ***/
.sf-shadow ul {
background: url('../img/shadow.png') no-repeat bottom right;
padding: 0 8px 9px 0;
-moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 17px;
-moz-border-top-right-radius: 17px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 17px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 17px;
}
.sf-shadow ul.sf-shadow-off {
background: transparent;
}
li.sf-search {
  background: inherit;
  float: right;
  line-height: 25px;
  background:transparent;
}
li.sf-search input {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin: 18px 6px 0 0;
  background: #fff url('../../../../img/search-zoom3.png') no-repeat left center;
  border:1px solid #777;
}


/* hack IE7 */
.sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited {height:34px !IE;}
.sf-menu li li {
width:200px;
background:#726f72 !IE;
}

#block_top_menu .category-thumbnail {
  display:none;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  float: none; }
  #block_top_menu .category-thumbnail div {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33333%; }
    #block_top_menu .category-thumbnail div img {
      max-width: 100%; }
#block_top_menu li.category-thumbnail {
  padding-right: 0; }




/* Mobile Item */
.sf-menu-phone-item { display:none; }
#sf-menu-phone-trigger { display:none; position:absolute; top:7px; right:0; background:url('http://www.dulcewashitape.com/themes/dulcewashitape/img/icon-mobile-nav.png') top right no-repeat #29addd; width:50px; height:50px; text-indent:-9999px; border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s; }
#sf-menu-phone-trigger:hover { background-color:#333; }
#sf-menu-phone-trigger.active { background-position:bottom right; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 999px) {
    .sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  {font-size:13px;}
}
/* Tablet Only Queries */
@media only screen and (min-width: 531px) and (max-width: 786px)  { 
    .sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  {font-size:12px;}
}

/* Phone Only Queries */
@media only screen and (max-width: 530px) { 
    .sf-menu a{
        top:5px;
    }
    #sf-menu-header {height:auto; }
    #sf-menu-top-nav {margin-left:-2%; margin-right:-2%;}
    /*.sf-menu {display:none; } */
    .sf-menu {width:100%; height:auto; margin:10px 0 0 0; position:static !important}
    .sf-menu li {width:100%; background:#f4f4f4;  border-top:1px solid #fff !important; border-bottom:1px solid #999 !important; -webkit-border-radius:0; border-radius:0; }
    .sf-menu li:hover {background:#de8686;}
    .sf-menu li ul {width:100%; position:static !important; background:#ccc;}
    .sf-menu li li {width:100% !important; background:#ccc; }
    /*.sf-menu li li li {display:none !important;}*/
    .sf-menu-phone-item { display:block; }
    #sf-menu-phone-trigger { display:block; }
    .sf-search {padding:10px;} 
    #searchbox {margin-left:15px;}
    #searchbox input[type="text"] {width:80%;}
    #searchbox input[type="text"]:focus, #searchbox input[type="text"]:hover {width:80%;}
    #searchbox .button {width:10%;}
    #header_logo { padding-right:50px; text-align:left !important;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for for help.
The height works, but now the cloud icon on top of the categories is misplaced, has to be a little higher. See it?

Comment: Just wait I will look at it and reply you